How to get Google Messages to accept image using commitContent() from custom third-party image keyboard?
Have followed official documentation and sample projects but for some reason I can't get Google Messages to accept my png images. It works for Facebook's Messenger, logs that it successfully commits the content but nothing actually happens for WhatsApp, and just logs that it's failed for Google Messages. There's almost documentation on how to commit media to these platforms using a third-party keyboard, wondering if anyone else has encountered this / might have a clue on what might be going on. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Relevant function:
private void sendImageToInputField(Uri imageUri) {
        String description = "Image"; // Description of the content
        String mimeType = "image/png";   // MIME type of the content


        InputConnection inputConnection = getCurrentInputConnection();
        EditorInfo editorInfo = getCurrentInputEditorInfo();
        int flags = InputConnectionCompat.INPUT_CONTENT_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION;

        if (inputConnection == null || editorInfo == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Input connection or editor info is null");
            return;
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "Preparing to commit content. URI: " + imageUri.toString());
        Log.d(TAG, "Target package: " + (editorInfo != null ? editorInfo.packageName : "null"));
        Log.d(TAG, "MIME types supported by target: " + (editorInfo != null ? Arrays.toString(EditorInfoCompat.getContentMimeTypes(editorInfo)) : "null"));

        ClipDescription clipDescription = new ClipDescription(description, new String[]{"image/png"});
        InputContentInfoCompat inputContentInfo = new InputContentInfoCompat(
                imageUri,
                clipDescription,
                null // Optional link URL
        );

        boolean result = InputConnectionCompat.commitContent(
                inputConnection,
                editorInfo,
                inputContentInfo,
                flags,
                null // Optional bundle for additional options
        );

        if (result) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Image successfully committed.");
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to commit image.");
            if (editorInfo != null) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Attempting to send to package: " + editorInfo.packageName);
                String[] mimeTypes = EditorInfoCompat.getContentMimeTypes(editorInfo);
                if (mimeTypes.length > 0) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Supported MIME types: " + Arrays.toString(mimeTypes));
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "No MIME types supported by the target field.");
                }
            }
        }
    }

